# How to edit metadata of an image in GIMP?

Tags: gimp, metadata

I am trying to edit Title, Description & meta tags of an image(.jpg) file. To do that, I am using GIMP 2.10.8. After opening the image file I am going to Image > Metadata > Edit Metadata. Then Metadata Editor window pops up. I am filling the necessary fields and click Write Metadata. Then exporting the file as an image(.jpg) file. Unfortunately, after the properties window of the exported image file, I am not getting any change in metadata. How can I overcome this issue?

Comment: What meta data are you editing specifically?

Comment: And how are you viewing the metadata? Does it show up as you entered it when you open the image in GIMP and look at the metadata editor again?

Comment: I am trying to add Description, tags. After adding the data I save the file and after closing the file from GIMP, I am not getting the meta data when I open the properties of the image.

Comment: What section of the Metadata Editor are you filling? Usually in jpeg files Gimp saves IPTC metadata.

Answer (score 0):

Gimp can be configured so as not to export metadata.  Is your instance of Gimp so configured?
Settings are available in Edit/Preferences/Image Import and Export/Export Policies."  (from https://docs.gimp.org/2.10/en/gimp-image-metadata.html)